# DLL Import fails on ESP was not properly saved accross a function call when using aruco V3

Tags: c#, opencv, dll, dllimport, aruco

I am trying to integrate [ArUco V3](https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) in a Unity project.

Therefore I created a .DLL which is imported as function like :

```
private static extern void functionName(uint, uint, float, float,float,float,IntPr,float)
```

The function in the header file is :

```
void functionName(unsigned int, unsigned int, float, float, float, float, float const*, float)
```

I am calling it with this method :

```
aruco::Markerdetector 
aruco::Cameraparameters(CalculateCameraMatrix(float, float, float, float), CalculateDistortionCoefficients(float const*), cvSize(uint, uint))
```

While running the application, opencv.core an opencvimgproc DLLs are constantly loaded and unloaded.

Is this a problem with the parameters conversion or is there a correlation with the calling convents which where used during compiling OpenCV.

Comment: Defect in your code. Provide a [mcve] and format it so that we can read it. Make use of the site help.

Answer (score 2):

Could solve the problem by adding the calling conventions to each dll import method separately

```
 [DllImport("Name", EntryPoint = "EntrypointName", CallingConvention =CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```